# Does VxWorks have strptime()

Tags: vxworks, time.h, wind-river-workbench

Does VxWorks support strptime()? In Linux, I have a string that I would like to convert into the time structure, however I don't see that function in VxWorks. Do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no such function exists in VxWorks.